# Select several values in nested associations

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations, data-structures

I have nested associations like this:

```
<|{"Country1","YEAR1"} -> {<|{"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"} -> 
 "Value1"|>, <|{"VARIABLE2", "MEASURE2"} -> "Value2"|>}, {"Country1",
"YEAR2"} -> {<|{"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"} -> 
 "Value1"|>, <|{"VARIABLE2", "MEASURE2"} -> "Value2"|>}, {"Country2", 
"YEAR1"} -> {<|{"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"} -> 
 "Value1"|>, <|{"VARIABLE2", "MEASURE2"} -> "Value2"|>},{"Country2", 
"YEAR2"} -> {<|{"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"} -> 
 "Value1"|>, <|{"VARIABLE2", "MEASURE2"} -> "Value2"|>}
```

and so on...Is there a way to select all Values e.g. for Country1 and for all Years but lets say only for the (sub)Key {"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"} for these Years? More specifically, the desired output would be a list like this

```
{Country1, YEAR1, Value1},{Country1, YEAR2, Value1}
```

Many thanks for you comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data form you provided this seems to work:

```
aData = <|{"Country1", 
     "YEAR1"} -> {<|{"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"} -> 
       "Value1"|>, <|{"VARIABLE2", "MEASURE2"} -> 
       "Value2"|>}, {"Country1", 
     "YEAR2"} -> {<|{"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"} -> 
       "Value1"|>, <|{"VARIABLE2", "MEASURE2"} -> 
       "Value2"|>}, {"Country2", 
     "YEAR1"} -> {<|{"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"} -> 
       "Value1"|>, <|{"VARIABLE2", "MEASURE2"} -> 
       "Value2"|>}, {"Country2", 
     "YEAR2"} -> {<|{"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"} -> 
       "Value1"|>, <|{"VARIABLE2", "MEASURE2"} -> "Value2"|>}|>;

m = {"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"};

c = "Country1";

Map[Append[#, Association[aData[#]][m]] &, Keys[KeySelect[aData, MemberQ[#, c] &]]]

(* {{"Country1", "YEAR1", "Value1"}, {"Country1", "YEAR2", "Value1"}} *)
```

### Update

> I need to select the variables for five specific countries. Another point would be if it is possible to further select only specific years (e.g. only from Year 5 to Year 10)

We make an appropriate criteria for `KeySelect`.

```
c = {"Country1"};

y = {"YEAR1"};

Map[Append[#, Association[aData[#]][m]] &, 
 Keys[KeySelect[aData, 
   Length[Intersection[#, c]] > 0 && 
     Length[Intersection[#, y]] > 0 &]]]

(* {{"Country1", "YEAR1", "Value1"}} *)
```

Comment: Thats very nice - many thanks for that! But in your solution both countries are included. This was just an easy code to illustrate my problem. In reality I have 20 Countries for 15 Years or so. And I need to select the variables for five specific countries. Another point would be if it is possible to further select only specific years (e.g. only from Year 5 to Year 10)

Comment: @M.A. Ok I fixed the code. With `KeySelect` you make selection of the keys that have the countries and years you want to focus on.

Comment: That is nearly perfect. But what if "m" is a list with multiple Variable-Measure combinations? I could solve this with a table but is there a more elegant way to obtain {"Country1", "YEAR1", "Value1", "Value2", "ValueX"} ?

Comment: @M.A. If `m` is a list of lists you can use `Map` or `Table` over `m` (as you say). "[...] but is there a more elegant way to obtain {"Country1", "YEAR1", "Value1", "Value2", "ValueX"} ?" -- I am not sure what do you mean by "more elegant" in the context of your data. You can always define a function for the extraction and your code will/can/might look elegant with it.

Comment: When i am using a table like this:

    Table[Map[Append[#, Association[aData[#]][m[[i]]]] &, 
 Keys[KeySelect[aData, 
   Length[Intersection[#, c]] > 0 && 
     Length[Intersection[#, y]] > 0 &]]],{i,1,Length[m]}] i will obtain

{"Country1", "YEAR1", "Value1"},{"Country1", "YEAR1", "Value2"}, and so on... Now I could manipulate that output to obtain {"Country1", "YEAR1", "Value1", "Value2", "ValueX"} but maybe there is a way to obtain that directly?

Comment: relating to my prevous comment: I solved my problem now by using a table but in another way:


 Map[Append[#, Table[Association[aData[#]][m[[i]]]], {i,1,Length[m]}] &, 
 Keys[KeySelect[aData, 
   Length[Intersection[#, c]] > 0 && 
     Length[Intersection[#, y]] > 0 &]]]

So I get

    {"Country1", "YEAR1", {"Value1", "Value2", "ValueX"}}

In order to the desired output I only need to use Flatten and Partition to obtain my desired output, however i am sure there is a more elegant way, isn't it?

Comment: @M.A. I will investigate this further later today...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would benefit from a change of your data structure.

#### 1. A more nested association

Given your initial set:

```
aData=<|
{"Country1","YEAR1"}->{<|{"VARIABLE1","MEASURE1"}->"Value111"|>,<|{"VARIABLE2","MEASURE2"}->"Value112"|>},
{"Country1","YEAR2"}->{<|{"VARIABLE1","MEASURE1"}->"Value121"|>,<|{"VARIABLE2","MEASURE2"}->"Value122"|>},
{"Country2","YEAR1"}->{<|{"VARIABLE1","MEASURE1"}->"Value211"|>,<|{"VARIABLE2","MEASURE2"}->"Value212"|>},
{"Country2","YEAR2"}->{<|{"VARIABLE1","MEASURE1"}->"Value221"|>,<|{"VARIABLE2","MEASURE2"}->"Value222"|>}|>;
```

let's turn it into:

```
newd = KeyValueMap[
   Association[#1[[1]] -> Association[#1[[2]] -> #2]] &, 
   Merge[#, Identity] & /@ aData] // Merge[#, Join @@ # &] &
```

> `<|"Country1" -> <|"YEAR1" -> <|{"VARIABLE1", 
>          "MEASURE1"} -> {"Value111"}, {"VARIABLE2", 
>          "MEASURE2"} -> {"Value112"}|>, 
>      "YEAR2" -> <|{"VARIABLE1", 
>          "MEASURE1"} -> {"Value121"}, {"VARIABLE2", 
>          "MEASURE2"} -> {"Value122"}|>|>, 
>    "Country2" -> <|"YEAR1" -> <|{"VARIABLE1", 
>          "MEASURE1"} -> {"Value211"}, {"VARIABLE2", 
>          "MEASURE2"} -> {"Value212"}|>, 
>      "YEAR2" -> <|{"VARIABLE1", 
>          "MEASURE1"} -> {"Value221"}, {"VARIABLE2", 
>          "MEASURE2"} -> {"Value222"}|>|>|>`

then you can make more readable query like that:

```
res=newd[[{"Country2", "Country1"}, {"YEAR1", "YEAR2"}, Key@{"VARIABLE1", "MEASURE1"}]]
```

> `<|"Country2" -> <|"YEAR1" -> {"Value211"}, "YEAR2" -> {"Value221"}|>, 
>    "Country1" -> <|"YEAR1" -> {"Value111"}, "YEAR2" -> {"Value121"}|>|>`

and to get the output you want:

```
Level[MapIndexed[Join /* RotateLeft, res, {2}], {2}] /. Key -> Identity
```

> `{{"Country2", "YEAR1", "Value211"}, {"Country2", "YEAR2", "Value221"}, {"Country1", "YEAR1", "Value111"}, {"Country1", "YEAR2", "Value121"}}`

#### 2. A Flat association

But why not try a flat association ?

```
flat = Flatten@
  Table[<|"Country" -> "C" <> ToString@i, 
    "Year" -> "Y" <> ToString@j, 
    "VarMeas" -> "VM" <> ToString@k|>, {i, 2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}]
```

> `{
>       <|Country->C1,Year->Y1,VarMeas->VM1|>,
>       <|Country->C1,Year->Y1,VarMeas->VM2|>,
>       <|Country->C1,Year->Y2,VarMeas->VM1|>,
>       <|Country->C1,Year->Y2,VarMeas->VM2|>,
>       <|Country->C2,Year->Y1,VarMeas->VM1|>,
>       <|Country->C2,Year->Y1,VarMeas->VM2|>,
>       <|Country->C2,Year->Y2,VarMeas->VM1|>,
>       <|Country->C2,Year->Y2,VarMeas->VM2|>}`

Then

```
Query[
Select[
(MemberQ[{"C1", "C2"}, #Country] && MemberQ[{"Y1"}, #Year]) &
], 
{"Country", "Year", "VarMeas"}]@flat // Values
```

> `{{"C1", "Y1", "VM1"}, {"C1", "Y1", "VM2"}, {"C2", "Y1", "VM1"},{"C2","Y1", "VM2"}}`

Comment: but it is not the output OP wanted.

Comment: @Kuba Right. I updated my answer.

Comment: @SquareOne: Thats also very nice but for my purpose it is better to keep the "main" key in the form {CountryX, YearX}; So I can add new (unknown) variables with "Merge" if it is necessary. Its about adding specific country-year variables from different .xls lists so this form seems to me most apropriate